# header function running order in PHP

Tags: php, header, location

```
<?php
header("Location:http://www.example.com");
header("Location:http://example.net");
?>
```

when I run this code, it is being redirected to example.net

---

why  is it being redirected to example.net whereas example.com comes before example.net?

Comment: this is why you always use `exit()` afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your second `header` replaces the first, because you are not using the optional `replace` parameter to `header`. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> **replace**
>
> The optional replace parameter indicates whether the header should replace a previous similar header, or add a second header of the same
>   type. By default it will replace, but if you pass in FALSE as the
>   second argument you can force multiple headers of the same type